# JSR-105 Referring for Signature Output

Tags: java, xml-signature

I'm working on the W3C Widgets Spec. I have a question with JSR-105 features.

Can anybody please tell me how to refer the XMLObject?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Signature>
  <SignedInfo>
    <Reference URI="#prop"/> <!-- How can I refer the Object? Isn't it the actual output? -->
  </SignedInfo>
  <Object Id="prop"/> 
</Signature>
```

I thought that I can make the XML part with those `newXXX` methods in the `XMLSignatureFactory`. But I couldn't figure out the way to make the `Reference` object for this. Because I couldn't find the way to make a `NodeSetData` for the `XMLObject` instance.

My current solution is...

1. Make an `org.w3c.dom.Document` containing the `Object` element and it's children.
2. And make a `URIDereferencer` returns a `NodeSetData` for the element.

Is this the best way? Is there any preferred way?